# Sci Chart: Spline Mountain Renderable Series Curve Issue

Tags: ios, swift, charts, scichart

I have generated SplineMountain Renderable Series Chart using sci chart. When There is less data provided to chart then it shows curves perfectly, But when I provide large amount of data then Chart doesn’t show any curve instead it’s shows straight line and spikes.

Step to Reproduce this issue.

1. Download Official Sci chart Demo.
2. Tap On 2D chart.
3. Select Spline Mountain Chart.
4. In that Chart You can see there is proper curves showing .

Now Change Spline Mountain Chart X and Y axis value with large amount of data.

Please put below data in yValue

```
y-value data: [142, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 150, 151, 150, 148, 147, 147, 149, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 153, 154, 152, 148, 146, 148, 150, 152, 151, 148, 147, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 150, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 152, 151, 151, 151, 150, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 154, 153, 152, 152, 151, 150, 150, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 148, 148, 148]
```

5. Please check that Spline Mountain Chart
   You can see there is no proper curves or no Curves , it's showing spikes and squares.

**Chart Example with Large data:** [image]

**Chart Example with Small data:** [image]

**Chart Demo Download Link**:  https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you